# How can a shell script tell if it is running in an xterm window with 256-color support?

Tags: linux, shell, colors, xterm, terminfo

I'm writing a shell script that I would like to use 256-color support when present.
In a just world, `xterm` would simply set the `TERM` environment variable to `xterm-256color` and I'd use `tput colors` to discover the support.

But we live in an unjust world.  `xterm` sets `TERM` to `xterm` even when launched with `TERM=xterm-256color`.  Is there anything I can do from within a shell script to discover whether the script is running with stdout connected to a tty running in a 256-color `xterm` window?  If so, I can set the environment variable myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for xterm version - $XTERM_VERSION.  Though I am not sure from which version xterm started to support 256 colors.   Other terminals (for example gnome-terminal), behave similarly to xterm but also set COLORTERM variable to correct terminal name (gnome-256color).

Comment: `XTERM_VERSION` dates from [2005](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_205), while 256-color support dates from [1999](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_112), however packages may/may not have configured that.

Answer (score 0):

Since most `xterm`-s are colorized these days, I would assume that the terminal has 256 colors, and make the script accept an option (perhaps `-monochrome` or `-no-colors`) otherwise.

BTW, I also see a reason for some power-user to force the `-monochrome`  behavior: on very slow connections (think of intercontinental `ssh`) it might be useful to disable colors to lower the bandwidth.

Comment: most term support only 16 colors.